# Can I use a real Apple ID for testing In-App Purchases while developing an app?

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

In other words, must I create "Test Users" accounts in iTunesConnect.apple.com in order for me or my testers to test my app's In-App Purchase with the "sandbox environment" fake App Store?

I have two scenarios:

- App running locally on device attached via USB cable
- Distributed to testers via TestFlightApp.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is in sandbox mode, you need an iTunes test account to test the In-App purchases. Both scenarios you describe apply. If you try to use real accounts, it will just throw you an error.

The same occurs with Game Center accounts.

Comment: Sorry, I now realize my title question and my first line question are worded in opposite direction. So maybe you should delete the word "Yes." from your answer. Is your answer that "Fake app store needs fake user accounts", and "real Apple ID accounts can only be used in the real App Store"?

Comment: @BasilBourque: Fake accounts for fake store - if you use real accounts in the fake store you'll just get an error. Also, I believe the fake accounts can indeed be used to make purchases in the real store, but you will need to supply credit card information.

Comment: 'Same occurs with Game Center accounts' - Really? Although Apple strongly advise against, it is possible to do some testing in GC with real accounts. So... in what case did you see this throwing an error?

Comment: @tea: Multiplayer matches. It "finds" the other players, but the match won't start. My game had 20+ testers, and nobody managed to play multiplayer until I gave them accounts. Also, some of the testers just crashed if they authenticated with real accounts, and we had to tell them to remain logged out to play the game. The reason why it "sometimes" works with real accounts is not clear, but it definitely doesn't behave normally. One particular problem is that GC players can see what others are playing. But what if your game doesn't exist yet? That's one reason the sandbox environment exists.